# What is function of .horizon files in file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, function

What is the function of the `.horizon` files that are present whenever a file geodatabase is created in ArcMap, I understand it is all proprietary formats for Esri, but is there any explanation?

I have attached a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It fact, Esri isn't "all proprietary formats" (though I wish shapefile was published with an open API; maybe we'd be done with it by now). But file geodatabase certainly is "unpublished".

Comment: The reverse engineered FGDB spec may be of interest, though it doesn't cover .horizon files - https://github.com/rouault/dump_gdbtable/wiki/FGDB-Spec

Comment: What happens when you delete it?

Comment: @nr_aus if we try deleting it, it will get created the next time you connect the file geodatabase to an ArcGIS Desktop application

Comment: Can you describe the data? As in, is it raster/vector? What does it represent? Is it in 3d? i just did a small test with a polygon Feature class, and the .horizon file doesn't get created.

Comment: @nr_aus Most of the time I do notice the horizon files but with some data I don't, I'm unsure, I have noticed it exist in 3D and also noticed it with File geodatabase Raster files. I tried out with a point feature class I could see it.